# Passing ArrayList<String> through Intents - tried everything on StackOverflow

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I'm having a problem with some easy stuff.

I'm trying to pass an `ArrayList<String>` through Intents like this:

```
        lupa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, lupa.class);
                    System.out.println(lista2); // Shows me the ArrayList<String>
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("lista",lista2);
                    System.out.println("done"); // Checking
            startActivity(intent);  
                    System.out.println("done2"); // Checking again
        }
```

'lista2' is a global variable:
            `ArrayList<String> lista2 = new ArrayList<String>();`, but I tried also with local variable, and also I tried doing it with Bundle.

What happens is: the application closes suddenly without any message and no message on the LogCat. I just get the three `System.out.println(...)` right but as I said, it gets closed without any message.

The problem is 100% on the `intent.putStringArrayListExtra("lista",lista2);` because if I comment it with `//` it takes me to the another activity.

What's wrong?

---

I discovered that I create a simple `ArrayList<String>` like this:

```
                ArrayList<String> lista3 = new ArrayList<String>();
            lista3.add("ola");
            lista3.add("k");
            lista3.add("ase");
```

it works fine with `intent.putStringArrayListExtra("lista",lista3);`

My `ArrayList<String>` is global, and I tried to copy it by:

```
ArrayList<String> lista3 = new ArrayList<String>();
lista3 = (ArrayList<String>)lista2.clone(); // lista2 is the global one
```

or

```
ArrayList<String> lista3 = new ArrayList<String>(lista2);
```

and nothing happened doing `intent.putStringArrayListExtra("lista",lista3);`

---

I got news again.

the `lista2.size()` is `5528` so I thought it was very big.

I'm doing FOR and adding things to the list, and I finally got that `3374` is the maximum `ArrayList<String>`'s size I can pass between activities. If I set `3375` the same happens (it closes with no message)...

---

Now I can get (I don't know why now) the Logcat:

```
11-01 00:19:27.025: D/PowerManagerService(2017): acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1000000  uid : 1000  pid : 2017  tag : ActivityManager
11-01 00:19:27.025: W/ActivityManager(2017): mDVFSLock.acquire()
11-01 00:19:27.045: V/AlarmManager(2017): waitForAlarm result :1
11-01 00:19:27.085: V/AlarmManager(2017): trigger ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or RTC_WAKEUP
11-01 00:19:27.085: W/AlarmManager(2017): FACTORY_ON= 0
11-01 00:19:27.095: V/AlarmManager(2017): waitForAlarm result :1
11-01 00:19:27.095: V/AlarmManager(2017): trigger ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or RTC_WAKEUP
11-01 00:19:27.135: E/JavaBinder(2017): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
11-01 00:19:27.185: W/ActivityManager(2017): Exception when starting activity com.example.ricettenapoli/.lupa
11-01 00:19:27.185: W/ActivityManager(2017): android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
11-01 00:19:27.185: W/ActivityManager(2017):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
11-01 00:19:27.185: W/ActivityManager(2017):    at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:731)
11-01 00:19:27.185: W/ActivityManager(2017):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:713)
11-01 00:19:27.185: W/ActivityManager(2017):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startSpecificActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:841)
11-01 00:19:27.185: W/ActivityManager(2017):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:1799)
11-01 00:19:27.185: W/ActivityManager(2017):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:1426)
11-01 00:19:27.185: W/ActivityManager(2017):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.completePauseLocked(ActivityStack.java:1174)
11-01 00:19:27.185: W/ActivityManager(2017):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.activityPaused(ActivityStack.java:1072)
11-01 00:19:27.185: W/ActivityManager(2017):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityPaused(ActivityManagerService.java:4467)
11-01 00:19:27.185: W/ActivityManager(2017):    at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:396)
11-01 00:19:27.185: W/ActivityManager(2017):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1695)
11-01 00:19:27.185: W/ActivityManager(2017):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
11-01 00:19:27.185: W/ActivityManager(2017):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-01 00:19:27.195: D/WindowManager(2017): PhoneWindowManager: focusChangedLw
```

Any idea?

---

EDIT: My `ArrayList<String>` was too big, so I stored it in a file and was loaded in the another activity.

Thank you!

Comment: are you getting any error messages on logcat?

Comment: No, no errors. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("lista",lista);
```

At lupa.class Activity you can get this list by:

```
ArrayList<String> lista = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("lista");
```

Comment: @RafaFirenze, can you post how do you add items to the ArrayList<String> ?

Comment: for(int i1 = 0; i1 < json.length(); i1++){
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i1);
                    String lat = c.getString("lat");
                    String lon = c.getString("lon");
More variables...
                    lista2.add(8*i1, lat);
       lista2.add(8*i1+1, lon);
Adding more variables...
}

The list is correct, I can see it.

Comment: Maybe you can surround the content of onClick method with try/catch block and e.printStackTrace(). Launch your app on debug mode and add a breakpoint to e.printStackTrace() line...